# How to reset $.?

Tags: perl, file-handling

I know `$.` shows the line number when `$/` is set to `"\n"`.

I wanted to emulate the Unix `tail` command in Perl and print the last 10 lines from a file but `$.` didn't work. If the file contains 14 lines it starts from 15 in the next loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $i;

open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0] or die "unable to open file $ARGV[0] :$! \n";
do { local $.; $i = $. } while (<$fh>);
seek $fh, 0, 0;

if ($i > 10) {
    $i = $i - 10;
    print "$i \n";
    while (<$fh>) {

        #local $.;# tried doesn't work
        #undef $.; #tried doesn't work

        print "$. $_" if ($. > $i);
    }
}
else {
    print "$_" while (<$fh>);
}

close($fh);
```

I want to reset `$.` so it can be used usefully in next loop.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but an alternative solution to your initial problem. In order to print last ten lines you can use this: `perl -nle 'push @tail, $_; shift @tail if @tail > 10; END {print foreach (@tail)}'  input.txt `

Comment: This discussion may help you :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036244/perl-is-there-a-built-in-function-to-clear-all-variable-values

Comment: Here is another implementation of `tail` in Perl 5: https://metacpan.org/source/BDFOY/PerlPowerTools-1.006/bin/tail#L142

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `local` with `$.` does something else than you think:

> Localizing $. will not
>                  localize the filehandle's line count. Instead, it will localize
>                  perl's notion of which filehandle $. is currently aliased to.

`$.` is not read-only, it can be assigned to normally.

```
1 while <$fh>;
my $i = $.;
seek $fh, $. = 0, 0;
```

Comment: but we can use local for $/ to set its value but for $. why can't we use local?

Comment: @ArruneshSingh: See `$.` in [perlvar](http://p3rl.org/perlvar). The quote is from there.

Answer (score 0):

You must reopen the file handle. Otherwise, as you have found, the line number just continues to increment

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($filename) = @ARGV;

my $num_lines;
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die qq{Unable to open file "$filename" for input: $!\n};
++$num_lines while <$fh>;

open $fh, '<', $filename or die qq{Unable to open file "$filename" for input: $!\n};

print "$num_lines lines\n";
while ( <$fh> ) {
    print "$. $_" if $. > $num_lines - 10;
}
```

Here's a neater way

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($filename) = @ARGV;

my @lines;
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die qq{Unable to open file "$filename" for input: $!\n};

while ( <$fh> ) {
  push @lines, $_;
  shift @lines while @lines > 10;
}

print @lines;
```